# Не реагирует бот Telegram Python

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Бот должен отправлять в ответ столько сердечек - сколько ему попросил пользователь, написав это при помощи цифр.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
    if message.text == type(1):
        y = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "❤" * y)
```

Однако при вводе каких либо данных - бот молчит

P.S - Пробовал еще без квадратных скобок

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types="text")
```

Comment: message.text - это тип string, который вы пытаетесь сравнить с типом int - вы получаете false.

Comment: if message.text == type(1) что за магию вы тут делаете ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
     if re.match(r"^[0-9]+$", message.text):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "❤" * int(message.text))
     else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправьте мне число.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного не понял ваш синтаксис и логику, поэтому предлагаю свое решение.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["text"])
def sub_text(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Количество сердечек')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, text)

def text(message):
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "❤" * int(message.text))
    except Exception:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не могу понять количество')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Мне надо изучить ваш код поближе

Comment: @shizanuti_armyanin если вам помог мой ответ, можете отметить его как правильный.

Comment: Заменять условные выражения конструкцией try/except - это не верный подход. Это не для этого придумано.

Comment: Но как же хорошо, что вашу реализацию можно остановить, только выполнением другой команды. И то что она падает после 2-х сообщений(0 и 0).